# Реализация жанров в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть проект, в котором нужно к фильмам привязывать жанры. Как это можно реализовать? Какие поля использовать для жанров?

Comment: "какие поля использовать для жанров"... id и название, очевидно? а в фильм - внешний ключ на жанр (или на несколько)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    """Жанр"""
    title = models.CharField('Название жанра', max_length=20)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField('Запись создана', default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Жанр'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Жанры фильмов'


class Film(models.Model):
    """Название фильма"""
    title = models.CharField('Название фильма', max_length=20)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField('Запись создана', default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фильм'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фильмы'
```

Comment: не хватает пояснений к коду.  Не все понимают, что и как работает. Например, использование ForeignKey может быть неприемлимым, если фильм относиться к нескольким жанрам (триллер и драма одновременно).

Comment: @Дмитрий, в таком случае надо использовать ManyToManyField?

Comment: да, мне то более чем понятно. Я за других переживаю